# Motivation behind AngularJs's data-ng-include - poor UX

Tags: ajax, templates, angularjs, user-experience

In AngularJs I can do this:

```
<header data-ng-include="views/header.html"></header>
```

which AFAIK asynchronously downloads `views/header.html` from client and interprets it as a template.

I want to ask if there is any sane motivation to use it because all I encountered with this was a pretty bad usex experience. I have a black Twitter Bootstrap header and this causes the header to show a moment later and therefore "hits" the user right in the eyes once all other content is visible.

On the top of that it does the request every time eventhough it just for a 304.

Comment: A webapp should never hit users right in the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ng-include to separate some HTML that is re-used, you can also bind the data-ng-include to a variable on your scope and change the view similar to what you get with ng-view and using the $routeProvider configuration.

I'm not entirely sure about the attempted reload and seeing the not modified response.  I would assume ng-include would operate under the same caching rules as a normal page but perhaps something is different since it does an AJAX request for it I assume.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to make it sync loading by adding a public counter to the `on-load` property of `ng-include`. And you can then wait the counter to increment to be the number of the templates loaded by `ng-include`, and then after all templates are loaded continue with other logic.

There are definitely some advantages of using `ng-include`. For example, you can use it together with `ng-switch` to conditionally load a template. And it also automatically creates a child scope if you want to isolate model from the current scope.

Hope it can shed some light on.